# why my simple reverse char* does not working?

Tags: c++

i wrote this code in two ways 
trying to run in visual studio 2012 - i open the project as simple console application and i get access valuation exception.

code 1

```
void revReq(char* str)
{
     if(*(str+1) != '\0')
          revReq(str+1);
     putchar(*str);
}
```

Code 2

```
void rev(char* str)
{
char* retVal = new char[strlen(str)]+1;

char* ptr = str + strlen(str)-1;
int i = 0;
while(ptr != str)
{
    retVal[i++]=*ptr;
    *ptr = '\0';
    ptr--;
}   
}
```

the inpus is

```
    char* n = "abcdef";
revReq(n);
```

the exception

Unhandled exception at 0x00B11E7C in Ex003.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: during memory allocation don't forget to add `+1` for null-terminator

Comment: Why are you ignoring the whole standard library? `std::reverse(str, str+strlen(str)-1);`. Even better with `std::string`.

Comment: this is academic practice ... i don't want to use <string> ...

Comment: I suspect your `(*str+1)` should be `*(str+1)`.

Comment: yes, thanks. ... *(str+1)   ... still does not work

Comment: ... and what @DavidYoung said...

Comment: For what input? It obviously won't work if the initial string is empty.

Comment: @Alan: You're right. I'm trying not to solve it for him.

Comment: the input is not empty.

Comment: @Yanshof: You'll find the function is much cleaner, clearer, and correct the first time if you write it to handle the empty string.

Comment: the string is not empty - this is academic practice and i don't know what i did wrong. i trying anything

Comment: @Yanshof: Academic or not, take a deep breath, walk around the block, and ask yourself what should the function do if the first character is null, then what it should do if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first function you compare a character in pointer str plus 1 with '\0' The condition can be equal to true only if char is equivalent to signed char and the internal code of *str is equal to 255 (-1).

```
void revReq(char* str)
{
     if((*str+1) != '\0')
          revReq(str+1);
     putchar(*str);
}
```

The valid code will look

```
void revReq( const char *s)
{
     if( *str )
     { 
          revReq( str + 1 );
          putchar( *str );
     }
}
```

The second function is also wrong. At least you have to write

```
char* retVal = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
```

instead of

```
char* retVal = new char[strlen(str)]+1;
```

Also there is a memory leak. The function has to return the reversed string.

The valid code will look as

```
char * rev( const char *s )
{
   size_t n = strlen( s );
   char *p = new char[ n + 1];

   const char *s1 = s + n;
   char *q = p;

   while ( s1 != s ) *q++ = *--s1; 
   *q = '\0';

   return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strlen(str) + 1
The strlen function returns the size of the string not including the null character '\0'

Comment: add this - still have same problem.

Comment: @Yanshof: You need the `+1` inside the `[]`.